# How to register gitlab runner?

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.site'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.site'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '~/docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '~/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '~/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'

  gitlab-runner:
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
    restart: always
    links:
      - gitlab
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
      - '~/docker/gitlab/gitlab-runner/data:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner/data'
      - '~/docker/gitlab/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw'
    environment:
      - CI_SERVER_URL=http://gitlab.site/ci
```

How to fix it

```
dedsec@dedsec-W65-67SB:~/docker/gitlab$ docker exec -it gitlab-runner /bin/bash
root@7aebabcd8f82:/# gitlab-runner register
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=31 revision=6214287e version=13.1.0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
[http://gitlab.site/ci]: 
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
52QTqtBsxNMeTXyYufq7
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[7aebabcd8f82]: giltab-runner
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
test
```

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=52QTqtBs status=couldn't execute POST against http://gitlab.site/api/v4/runners: Post http://gitlab.site/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 157.230.23.8:80: i/o timeout
    PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```